# In screen lock background play music and controls

Tags: react-native-video

I am using React native video npm - In screnio In play audio in after screen lock .

Im using this type of code

```
<Video
    source={{
        uri: this.props.data.Link,
    }}                 
    controls
    playInBackground={true}
    playWhenInactive={true}
    disableFocus={false}
    audioOnly={true}
    preventsDisplaySleepDuringVideoPlayback={false}
    pictureInPicture={true}
    ignoreSilentSwitch={'inherit'}
    lockControl={true}
    allowsExternalPlayback={true}
    automaticallyWaitsToMinimizeStalling={false}
/>
```

Its working in lock screen play audio but controls are disabled please anyone help me

videos are playing at a time in the background without viewing the videos and another problem is all videos controls={true}  in lock screen
Any configure in ios upto 14 version Its fine working in ios 12 please any configuration in xcode or swift language to react native code